# How to convert Objective C project to Windows Mobile

Tags: ios, windows-10-mobile, winobjc

I am working on hybrid app majorly built on HTML5, CSS3, javascript and wrapped over PhoneGap to create apk, ipa and xap/appx file. With the latest Microsoft announcements, its possible to convert your iOS project to Windows project. Can anyone give a small tour of how to convert an existing iOS project to Windows mobile project?

Answer (score 4):

You need to follow the steps given below:

- You need to custom install Visual Studio 2015 with UWP (Universal Windows Platform) on Windows 10 system.
- If you have Windows 7 or 8 machine and not Windows 10, you will need a Windows 10 mobile device to run the application.
- Download the WinObjC SDK from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC). You can either directly download the SDK from the link or download the source code and create the SDK by following the steps given on this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/wiki).
- Now keep your iOS application code (developed using Objective C) ready and follow the steps under "Using vsimporter" heading at the same [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/wiki).
- Before building the application, right-click the solution and set it as a startup project.
- Build the application and it will run on your Windows 10 device.

Comment: no such file or directory: 'Application\winobjc\msvc\\objcrt\objc_2stage_init.h'

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the answer already provided, to convert a Objective-C project to Windows is required to use the tool vsimporter.

This tool is present in open source bridge Project from Microsoft GitHub (https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC).

***Check the Readme file before to start

Using vsimporter

The vsimporter tool enables you to import your Xcode project into a new Visual Studio Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app project with Objective-C support.

To use the tool:

1. Download the prebuilt SDK from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC/releases/download/0.1-preview/winobjc.zip) and extract the files to a directory (for example  `c:\winobjc`)
2. From a command prompt, navigate to the directory containing your Xcode project, for example  `c:\winobjc\samples\WOCCatalog`
3. At the command prompt, run vsimporter.exe
   `c:\winobjc\samples\WOCCatalog> ..\..\bin\vsimporter.exe`
4. A Visual Studio solution file is created in your current directory, double click this file to open your project in Visual Studio
5. Press Ctrl-F5 to build your app and run it on your PC.

You can also pass the -i option at the command line to run the vsimporter tool in interactive mode. Interactive mode lets you see and select the specific configurations of the Xcode project that you wish to import. By default vsimporter creates a Visual Studio solution that targets Windows 10. If you'd like to target Windows 8.1 (Phone or Store), use the -format option and specify one of winstore8.1, winphone8.1, or winstore10 (winstore10 is the default).

For help running vsimporter, use the -help option at the command line to see the full set of supported options.

To see the complete tutorial, please visit this [link](http://talkitbr.com/2015/08/18/portando-apps-ios-para-windows/)